# sqlite database can not insert more than two fields in one table using cordova,

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I try to enter data into sqlite in cordova, I made one database and one table with two fields was successful, when making three field error occurs when the insert, What is wrong?

This my script with 3 field on 1 table.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var db;

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady(){
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "samplingapp.db"});
    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sampling_m (id integer primary key, kode_pohon text, bag_pohon text, date text)');
    });
}

$("#insert").click(function(){
  var kode_pohon=$("#kode_pohon").val();
  var bag_pohon=$("#bag_pohon").val();
  var date=$("#date").val();
  console.log(kode_pohon +""+ bag_pohon +""+ date); 
  db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO sampling_m (kode_pohon, bag_pohon, date) VALUES (?,?)";             
        transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [kode_pohon,bag_pohon,date]
            , function(tx, result) {
                 alert('Inserted');
            },
            function(error){
                 alert('Error occurred'); 
            });
    });
});


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO sampling_m (kode_pohon, bag_pohon, date) VALUES (?,?)";
```

should be

```
var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO sampling_m (kode_pohon, bag_pohon, date) VALUES (?,?,?)";
```

so that the date will be saved.

Comment: it works nice thank you, I am still learning cordova, whether each field should use (?) according to the number of fields created?

Comment: Yes. Each ? serves as a placeholder for the values you want to bind to the sql query.

Comment: hello @Awoi, I found the error again while making 4 field work but when the field 5 with same script error when appropriate,

Comment: What do you mean? Please expound

Comment: hello @Awoi, I just had a reply yet. i try this succes,`var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO sampling_m (kode_pohon,bag_pohon,tanggal,lokasi) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"`;  but i try this error `var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO sampling_m (kode_pohon,bag_pohon,tanggal,lokasi, estate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"; `

Comment: What is the error? Are there no values saved for the second query?

Comment: Thanks @Awoi, error can not store data. after transaction.executeSql result function(error), all script same i just add new field estate and cannot store data.

Comment: can you help me @Awoi